# How to use Camel route in separate XML file

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have two separate Camel routes defined in separate XML files.  Call them route A and B.

I would like to direct route B to first call route A, before passing the result to route B.

How should I go about doing so?  So far I am looking at the `direct` DSL.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please clarify, because my english is poor. You want to send request to B,  but before processing request in route B you want call route A? am I right?

Comment: Is your question about the two XML files only? How are these two XML files related/linked? Are they both included somewhere else? Does one include the other? Same Camel context? etc.

Comment: Yes, that is correct! An intermediate route is triggered to return an intermediate object, before being used by a secondary route.

Comment: I have found the answer, it can be done by using `direct-vm` directive. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define the secondary route, and link both routes together using `vm-direct`.

When called, objects stored as variables in secondary route can be referenced by the earlier route, i.e. the routes are executed sequentially and pend on the secondary route's completion.

Like so:

Primary route:

```
<To uri="direct-vm:....>
<!-- variables if stored by secondary route available here -->
```

Secondary route:

```
<Route>
    <From uri="direct-vm:.....>
</Route>
```